# Use Regex / Powershell to rename files

Tags: regex, powershell

How does one rename the following files (New => Old):

> **filename__Accelerated_C____Practical_Programming_by_Example.chm**
>   -> *C Practical Programming by Example.chm*
>
> **filename__Python_Essential_Reference__2nd_Edition_.pdf**
>   -> *Python Essential Reference 2nd Edition.pdf*
>
> **filename__Text_Processing_in_Python.chm**
>   -> *Text Processing in Python.chm*

Comment: First one should be **Accelerated C++ Practical Programming by Example** imho.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should work:

```
ls | %{ ren $_ $(($_.name -replace '^filename_+','') -replace '_+',' ') }
```

Expanding the aliases and naming all argument, for a more verbose but arguably more understandable version, the following is equivalent

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $(($_.Name -replace '^filename_+','') -replace '_+',' ') }
```

Comment: Why using `$` in the second parameter. I found this working too:

`ls | % { ren $_ (($_ -replace 'filename_+','') -replace '_+',' ')}`

Comment: forgot my comment, $ is necessary to cut off last space before the file extension :). Your regex works perfectly!

Comment: In case anybody else has the same problem: If, for whatever reason, using the foreach-block results in a "cannot rename because item does not exist" error, try using the script-block as argument to -NewName, as shown in the answer by user @stej (works for me). I cannot understand why this should make any difference. Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: This answer could be considerably improved if it pointed to some documentation to help beginner readers understand the regex machinery in it.

Answer (score 54):

Try this one:

```
Get-ChildItem directory `
        | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^filename_+','' -replace '_+',' ' }
```

Note that I just pipe the objects to `Rename-Item`, it is not really needed to do it via `Foreach-Object` (alias is `%`).

**Update**

I haven't anything documented about the 'magic' with scriptblocks. If I remember correctly, it can be used if the property is `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true`:

```
function x{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$o,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$prefix)
    process {
        write-host $prefix $o
    }
}
gci d:\ | select -fir 10 | x -prefix { $_.LastWriteTime }
```

Comment: Woohoo. +1 for eliminating the unnecessary `Foreach` pipeline stage.  :-)

Comment: hey cool. The docs don't say you could use a scriptblock as a param there. Is this a feature of many other cmdlets?

Comment: @zdan, I don't know where it is documented. Maybe found it on a blog. Nobody has answered so far (question on Twitter). See my edited answer.

Comment: @stej   It basically expands the scriptblock into a foreach-object behind the scenes.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/flexible-pipelining-with-scriptblock-parameters/ quote form this site: "What happens is this case is that this SCRIPTBLOCK will be run for each and every object in the pipeline and the results will be bound to this parameter. "

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$filename = $filename -creplace '_+\.', '.'
$filename = $filename -creplace '_+', ' '
```