# How would I batch rename file in a directory from [string x]_[string y].properties to [string y]_[string x].properties?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-rename

I was manually renaming about 450 files for a project I'm working on and realized 400 in that it would be easier if "y" came first in the order, but I was too far in by that point to change it. Is there I way I could automatically do that?

Example:

```
-cloth_ball.properties
-cloth_puppet.properties
-plastic_ball.properties
-plastic_puppet.properties
-wooden_ball.properties
-wooden_puppet.properties
```

Needs to be:

```
-ball_cloth.properties
-ball_plastic.properties
-ball_wooden.properties
-puppet_cloth.properties
-puppet_plastic.properties
-puppet_wooden.properties
```

I looked for other batch renaming options for help, but I couldn't find any that would help with this specific issue.

Comment: As you have already received an answer to your off topic code request in a particular scripting language, I have removed the other scripting language tag, along with another. Here we help you to fix a specific issue with your own code attempt, we do not produce a code to order service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of strings:

```
$strings = @(
    '-cloth_ball.properties'
    '-cloth_puppet.properties'
    '-plastic_ball.properties'
    '-plastic_puppet.properties'
    '-wooden_ball.properties'
    '-wooden_puppet.properties'
)
```

You can first use the regex pattern `(?<=-)([^_]+)_([^.]+)` with `-replace` operator, and then `Sort-Object` for sorting them:

```
$strings -replace '(?<=-)([^_]+)_([^.]+)', '$2_$1' | Sort-Object
```

See https://regex101.com/r/e7kggt/2 for regex details.

Comment: Thank you! So how would I use this in a directory of files? 

Say, I have a folder called 'items' with all of these inside and I need to rename every single file in that directory with this rule. How would I format that for Powershell and/or batch?

Comment: @Zenith have a look at `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item` documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Building off the previous answer as well as the answer here ([Use Regex / Powershell to rename files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574648/use-regex-powershell-to-rename-files)), you can do this by piping Get-ChildItem for your folder "MyFolder" into Rename-Item.

```
Get-ChildItem MyFolder | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '([^_]+)_([^\.]+)\.(.+)', '$2_$1.$3'}
```

As mentioned, regex101 will explain this. See here for this example: https://regex101.com/r/UulvlB/1